# Content Graphic Was Pushed Down - Need Help

Tags: content-management

I modified html codes generated by Firework, and now graphic was pused down I dont know how to fix it. Sorry Im still using tables, mixing up with css to create the list items....please help....What I did was extend the original graphic to make it taller to fit the list menu

http://imageoneads.com/work/inventory.htm

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you removed one row from the center section.

On the left side, in the cell containing `r10_c1.jpg`, change `rowspan="2"` to `rowspan="1"`

On the right side, change `rowspan="9"` to `rowspan="8"`

Comment: That is awesome. It fixed everything. Thanks so much egrunin. It was always the issue when I move objects around.

http://imageoneads.com/work/inventory.htm

Have a great day!

Comment: @Tran: You can accept this as the correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the left of this answer.